# How to get value from an HTA file using VBScript or VBA

Tags: vba, vbscript, hta

I am running VBScript and trying to get values from checkbox in HTA file (HTA window is already displayed). What is important, VBScript is a separate file - this code shoud not be included in  section in HTA file because of some reasons/restrictions.

I think I should set this HTA window and create object somehow, but really do not how.

```html
<html>
<head>
<HTA:APPLICATION ID="objHTAHelpomatic" APPLICATIONNAME="Checklist" SCROLL="no" SINGLEINSTANCE="yes" WINDOWSTATE="maximize" />
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" name="c1" value="1" checked>ONE<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="c2" value="1" checked>TWO<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="c3" value="1" checked>THREE<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Could anyone suggest me how to get those values? For example to double click on VBS file and display values in `MsgBox`?

Comment: You can read about reading information from HTML using VBA from (https://www.encodedna.com/excel/extract-contents-from-html-element-of-a-webpage-in-excel-using-vba.htm)

Comment: Basically I know something how to work on it, how to connect with browswer and find there what I need, but to do that I have to Set IE = New InternetExplorer and so one. In this case my code have to find a window, recognize it and then find something inside.